# How to use DeduplicationHandler in Monolog?

Tags: logging, duplicates, monolog

I'm new to Monolog, but I have already found it very useful. But I'd like to eliminate some of the duplication I'm getting.

I can't find any examples of using `DeduplicationHandler` in Monolog in a PHP script. I've read about it, and the arguments it takes, but I can't get it to work.
I get the error

> construct() must implement interface Monolog\Handler\HandlerInterface, null given

but figure out how to implement that.

Would using it go something like this?

```php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\HandlerInterface;
use Monolog\Handler\DeduplicationHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;
    
$logger = new Logger('user_pg');
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler(__DIR__ . '/log/user.log', Logger::DEBUG));
$handler = $logger->pushHandler(new HandlerInterface( __DIR__ . '/log/duplicates.log', Logger::ERROR));
$logger->pushHandler(new DeduplicationHandler($handler, 
$deduplicationStore = __DIR__ . '/log/duplicates.log', 
$deduplicationLevel = Logger::ERROR, $time = 60, $bubble = true));
```

I'm obviously shooting in the dark here, since I can't find any examples of using it in a PHP script like this.

Answer (score 1):

The DeduplicationHandler works like a wrapper for the handler you want the deduplication to apply to. In your case, you would supply the StreamHandler as the first parameter of the deduplication handler. I've modified your code to demonstrate this.

```php
<?php

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;
use Monolog\Handler\DeduplicationHandler;
use Monolog\Logger;

$logger = new Logger('user_pg');

$streamHandler = new StreamHandler(__DIR__ . '/log/user.log', Logger::DEBUG);
$logger->pushHandler(new DeduplicationHandler($streamHandler, __DIR__ . '/log/duplicates.log', Logger::ERROR, 60, true));
```